# Can quantum entanglement work like this?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

Lets say you have two entangled particles (A,B) and you already measured theirs spins and know that A has z+ and B has z-

What will happen if after the measurement you will set the spin of B to z+ (don't know if this is possible, but lets say that yes), will the spin of A change to opposite?

Comment: If $A$ is in the state $z^+$ and $B$ is in the state $z^-$, then the pair is in state $z^+\otimes z^-$, which is (obviously) not entangled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you can't really do that pre-measurement when they are entangled either.

See (["FTL" Communication with Quantum Entanglement?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/203831/ftl-communication-with-quantum-entanglement/203893#203893)) for a more-general explanation I recently did about what quantum entanglement is; it may help demystify the basic idea of what entangled systems do together.