# Quantum Entanglement and transfer of time information, is it possible?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, faster-than-light, superposition

If two particles are quantum entangled...let’s call them particle A and particle B.   You measure the state of particle A.

At this point, can you know the exact time at which the particle B goes from superposition into a known state due to the remote measurement of particle A, only by waiting on particle B without knowledge of A?

If that’s possible, then it seems to me, you could use Morse code to send information over quantum entangled particals.

Consider the following protocol:

- logic 0 defined as $\le 50$ millisecond time interval in superposition before not in superposition detected
- logic 1 defined as $\le 100$ milliseconds and $\gt 50$ millisecond time interval in superposition before not in superposition detected
- $\gt$ 100 millisecond time interval of superposition state defined as “Hangup”
- “hangup” followed by “logic 0” defined as “Start”

I define “superposition” as the “quantum entangled state”, Where the “Schrödinger's cat” is both alive and dead at the same time.

Who really cares about the changed the vale of an entangled particle from the transmitter side... I just want to know if particle B is in a superposition or a non-superposition state, and the exact time that state transitions from superposition to a known state... and without direct knowledge of particle A

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The choice of measurement basis on one half of an entangled state affects the other half. Can this be used to communicate faster than light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/100864/) Also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/203831/123208 & the other questions linked there.

Comment: I guess your core question is: Can we tell if B is in a superposition or not?

Comment: Yes! That’s my question... can you know that information from receiver B’s side without prior knowledge of knowing that transmitter A will take a measurement of its entangled particle at exact 12:30 Pm on 6/26/2020. Can receive  B sit there and know that it’s received particle is in superposition or known state with out knowing when A is scheduled to measure its entangled particle.

Answer (score 2):

> Can you know the exact time at which the particle B goes from superposition into a known state due to the remote measurement of particle A, only by waiting on particle B without knowledge of A?

No, you cannot tell if particles B & A are entangled without measuring both particles and comparing the measurements, and to compare the measurements you need to transmit information via a classical channel, i.e., at the speed of light, or slower.

So not only can you not tell if B is entangled without performing a measurement on it, you can't even tell if it was entangled after you *do* make the measurement, until you learn the results of A's measurement.

Comment: In that case, I think superposition doesn't really exist... it’s just a Calibration of states between two particles so that they follow the same random sequence even if separated.. just because the measurement appears to change random doesn’t mean it’s really random...  that just means they don’t know the mechanism or law to recreate it...like an enigma machine... it’s a black box that generates random numbers...two enigma machines generate the same sequence when they have the same seed...

Comment: @Convolver I think you mean "correlation", not "calibration". Technically, there aren't 2 states, there's 1 state that "contains" 2 particles. And Bell's theorem proves mathematically that whatever mechanism enforce the correlation it cannot use some local hidden variable inside each particle that determines the result of a measurement.

Answer (score 0):

Convolver, you commented PM 2Rings answer as follows:

> In that case, I think superposition doesn't really exist...

Take the case of two colored marbles. Indeed there isn’t a superposition. Different from two photons, made by [Spontaneous parametric down-conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_parametric_down-conversion). The photons directions are entangled, but the directions (together) are random around 360°.

This entanglement you measure with two polarized foils for example. But the outcome of the measurements needs statistics. In some measurements you not get any result, in some you get only one photon measured behind the foils and only in some you get the correlation. From this one conclude about the entanglement process of the designed by (wo)man Spontaneous parametric down-conversion.

Once established, it is incomprehensible to turn it into a mystery. You name it:

> it’s just a Calibration of states between two particles so that they follow the same random sequence even if separated.. just because the measurement appears to change random doesn’t mean it’s really random...

We are not able - at least at the moment - to control the directions of the entangled partcles, again you name it:

> that just means they don’t know the mechanism or law to recreate it...like an enigma machine... it’s a black box that generates random numbers...two enigma machines generate the same sequence when they have the same seed...

Congratulations on your findings. But sometimes it takes a hundred years or more to change your thinking. That is science with its stable common thinking. Otherwise science would not work and would be like the Tower of Babel without understanding each other. So be patient, always with your thoughts and talk about them when you have the slightest chance of being heard.