Does quantum entanglement really involve influencing particles "across distances", or is it just a correlation that we observe after measurement?
I’ve been learning about quantum entanglement and I’m struggling to understand the full picture. Here’s what I’m thinking:
In entanglement, we have two particles (let's call them A and B) that are described as a single, correlated system, even if they are far apart. For example, if two particles are entangled with total spin 0, and I measure particle A to have clockwise spin, I immediately know that particle B will have counterclockwise spin, and vice versa.
However, here’s where my confusion lies: It seems like the only reason I know the spin of particle B is because I measured particle A. I’m wondering, though, isn’t it simply that one particle always has the opposite spin of the other, and once I measure one, I just know the spin of the other? This doesn’t seem to involve influencing the other particle "remotely" or "faster than light" – it just seems like a direct correlation based on the state of the system, which was true all along.
So, if the system was entangled, one particle’s spin being clockwise and the other counterclockwise was always true. The measurement of one doesn’t really influence the other, it just reveals the pre-existing state.
Am I misunderstanding something here? Or is it just a case of me misinterpreting the idea that entanglement “allows communication faster than light”?

You seem to be muddling various quantum concepts. See joshphysics’ answer here to disentangle ;) some of these https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/54977/337317.

You are missing the concept of superposition.

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/203831/ftl-communication-with-quantum-entanglement/203885#203885

Bell’s Theorem (1964) addresses most of your thinking. That should be your next area to study in order to better understand entanglement.

100% you are right.             Isn't there a much simpler way to explain why quantum entaglement at distance isn't utile and Can you force the spin measurement on an electron? and therein „You are absolutely right when you interpret the results of the entanglement experiments as you describe above. However, science is based on consensus…“

Here is what you're missing.
You take one entangled particle.  I'll take the other.  I'll take it someplace very far away, in fact.
Now take your measuring apparatus, orient it north/south, and measure your particle's spin.  I'll do the same.  100% of the time, we will get opposite results.
Now orient your apparatus, say, northeast/southwest, while I continue to hold mine north/south.  We make our measurements, and now we get opposite results about 70% of the time.
Or orient your apparatus east/west.  Now we get opposite results 50% of the time.
Or orient your apparatus north-northeast/south-southwest.  Then we get opposite results about 85% of the time.
Likewise if you keep your apparatus fixed north/south and I start changing my apparatus's orientation.
Go try and explain that as simple discovery of pre-existing correlations, using just classical concepts.
So the particles don't have pre-existing spins that we are simply discovering.  But there is even more to the story:  It turns out that with a little analysis of the particular correlations we observe, you can prove that the particles don't even have a pre-existing joint probability distribution for the spins they'll exhibit when measured in different orientations.
So the first (mild) surprise is that there are no pre-existing spins; the second (far more unsettling, at least before you start thinking like a quantum mechanic) is that there's not even a probability distribution for those spins.
Finally, you're last paragraph says this:

The measurement of one doesn’t really influence the other, it just reveals the pre-existing state.

It is certainly true that the measurement of one does not influence the other.  It is also true that there is no pre-existing joint probability distribution for the outcomes of the spin measurements (which rules out any sort of pre-existing "state" in the sense that you appear to be using that word).   And it is also true that according to classical physics and probability theory, those two statements contradict each other.  That's why quantum mechanics takes some getting used to.

thanks for your answer. a question to clarify: I understand from your example that the spin can change multiple time, but I ask it anyway.... once you have performed the measurement and found out the spin, can the spin of that particle change later? or will be for ever remain the same? if can change, how can it change? it changes just by moving the measuring apparatus? and if changes, does it mean that the other entangled-with particle changes too accordingly, in "live"?

“It is also true that there is no pre-existing state”. Do you mean classical probabilistic state, am I right? The quantum state pre-exists…

Non existence of a classical probabilistic state is quite unrelated with entanglement. It is just a consequence of the quantum notion of probability, which is not defined on a classical probability space but it is assigned on a non Boolean lattice…A way to partially reintroduce classical probabilities is  the use of the notion of contextuality.

A bone to pick. You said: “ It is certainly true that the measurement of one does not influence the other.” This is misleading, because there is both theoretical (Bell) and experimental evidence that such influence exists. But such evidence is not conclusive. There is absolutely no experimental evidence supporting your statement, but there is theoretical support for it. The matter is currently open to interpretation.

@ValterMoretti :  I was using the word "state" in the sense that I took the OP to be using it, but you're right that this invited confusion.  I've rewritten the final paragraph.

@allexj :  Response to your comment:  Once you've made a measurement, the particles are no longer entangled.  I am envisioning repeating the experiment many times, with a new pair of particles each time, but all of the particle pairs prepared identically.

@DrChinese:  There is ample theoretical and empirical reason to believe that there is no joint probability distribution for the outcomes of various measurements.  I'd resist the implication that this implies "influence", but that's more a statement about my preferred use of language than a statement about physics.   Certainly (at least according to mainstream physics) there can be no causal influence in the sense of a transfer of information.

Again, a bone: “Once you've made a measurement, the particles are no longer entangled”. The measurement point is not an endpoint to entanglement. Surprisingly, a particle can become entangled after measurement in delayed choice swapping cases. Entangled systems do not respect Einsteinian causal order, as I mentioned already (which you deny). But see: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.4834 I agree there is no transfer of useful information.


"it is certainly true that the measurement of one does not influence the other".... but here they tell me this statement is wrong: https://www.reddit.com/r/QuantumPhysics/comments/1hl2r45/comment/m3vcwb9/  referring to the pilot wave theory


@DrChinese:   Suppose someone asks what happens to a car after it is disassembled.   I answer that after the disassembly, there is no car.  Someone else (someone, I will mention, who frequently posts good and useful answers) comes along to pick a bone, pointing out that someone might reassemble that car.  I think I would respond thus:  "That's both as true and as off the point as objecting to the statement that after measurement there is no entanglement, because even though the entanglement is destroyed, someone might come along and recreate it."

@allexj :  People are quibbling about what the word "influence" means.  That's a dispute about language, not about physics.  The key point is that no information travels from one particle to the other, and in that sense there can be no causal influence.

@WillO yeah no information, because I cannot force a particle to some value so I cannot force the other one to the opposite value: basically I cannot send data. but you said that "there is certainly no influence", you did not say "there is no information traveling"... so it's confusing.... to recap and conclude: is it true that ONLY AFTER I measure my particle, something is INFLUENCING/interactingWith the other one to make it be the other sign? or is it wrong? I mean, is something happening AFTER the particle measuring that is gonna put the other particle to be to the correct state?

@Will, I agree that some of these issues might be semantics. I always like your answers (which are useful, which is a compliment), which is why I mentioned a mere “bone”. I personally believe the cited experiment demonstrates a remote causal influence, but without signaling ability. How to properly conceive or interpret this effect is difficult, and remains to be determined conclusively.

@allexj:  No, nothing is happening afterward.  In other words, there is no window of time in which particle A has been measured and particle B's statistics fail to reflect that measurement.

@WillO do you agree with this comment about that? https://www.reddit.com/r/QuantumPhysics/comments/1hl2r45/comment/m40qdiv/
